# How to find prime ideals of $3\Bbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Which one of these is prime of $3\Bbb Z$?

$42\Bbb Z$,$24\Bbb Z$,$12\Bbb Z$,$9\Bbb Z$ and $33\Bbb Z$

I tried to check their factor groups if they are integral domains. because

> An ideal I in a ring R is a prime ideal if the quotient ring R/I is an
>   integral domain.

$3\Bbb Z/42\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z/14\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z_{14}$ not an integral domain so not a prime ideal.

Is this approach wrong?

Comment: so $1\notin 3\Bbb Z/42\Bbb Z$ my isomorpishms are all wrong

Comment: $3\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z_3$ and $3\Bbb Z/33\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z_{11}$. In general $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a prime ideal iff $p$ is prime moreover its a field.

Comment: @user26857 so it is the rule : "let n be integer, prime ideals of $n\Bbb Z$ is $np\Bbb Z$ where $p\neq n$. is this correct? can we show this like : let $a,b \in n\Bbb Z$. if $a.b\in np\Bbb Z$ then $np|ab$. since p is prime n|b or n|a. so $a \in Z_n$ or $b \in Z_n$.

Comment: how is $3\Bbb Z/9 \Bbb Z$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3$ ?? (as a ring)

Comment: Isn't it easier to just go by the definition of prime ideal, namely, $J$ is a prime ideal if $ab$ in $J$ implies $a$ in $J$ or $b$ in $J$? So, e.g., $6$ and $21$ are in $3{\bf Z}$ and not in $42{\bf Z}$, but $6\times21$ is in $42{\bf Z}$, so $42{\bf Z}$ is not prime in $3{\bf Z}$.

Comment: @mwomath $3\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$ is a three element ring in which all elements square to zero: it is not $\Bbb Z_3$ *at all.*